# Convert a colum to mutiple colum with pivot or aggreate fucntion in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a data like this in sql table

[image]

```
String

914-3000-0002
03/14/2018 13:03:10
03/16/2018 13:03:10
26074
```

Need to convert like the below(4 columns needs to change)

```
task no          start date             end date             id
914-3000-0002 | 03/14/2018 13:03:10  | 03/16/2018 13:03:10 | 26074
```

Comment: How is this going to generalize to more than 4 rows?

Comment: (1) Include sample data and desired results as *text* in the question.  (2) Tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Tab TABLE(String VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES ('914-3000-0002')
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES ('03/14/2018 13:03:10')
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES ('03/16/2018 13:03:10')
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES ('26074')

SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN D.RN=1 THEN D.String END)[task no]
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN D.RN=2 THEN D.String END) [start date]
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN D.RN=3 THEN D.String END) [end date]
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN D.RN=4 THEN D.String END) [id]
FROM(
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))RN 
    FROM @Tab
    )D
```

**Output:**

```
task no         start date          end date            id
914-3000-0002   03/14/2018 13:03:10 03/16/2018 13:03:10 26074
```

Comment: The `row_number()` can put the values in any order.

Comment: Yeah @GordonLinoff, I know that. But in that case we have no way.

Comment: This answer is not correct, because it assumes that `order by (select null)` will returns the results in some canonical order.  This is simply not true.  The problem cannot be solved as stated; a column is needed to specify the ordering of the table.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this safely, you need a column that specifies the ordering.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So:

```
select max(case when seqnum = 1 then string end) as taskno,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then string end) as startdate,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then string end) as enddate,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then string end) as id
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by ?) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

The `?` is for the ordering column.  Without an ordering column, you might try to do this and the code might seem to work -- but it might break at any point.

Comment: Thanks  a lot Team for the reply. Very fast reply :)